# Why was the Space Stone used to control people and give powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *The Avengers*,

> Loki uses the Tesseract to control people, such as Dr. Selvig and Haweye.

In *Captain Marvel*,

> when Carol Danvers shoots the ship's engine, the Tesseract ends up giving her superpowers.

Why was the Space Stone used to do this?

Should not these be the functions of the Mind Stone and the Power Stone, respectively?

Comment: I rolled back the edit that corrected the OP's mistake as it invalidated the answers and at least had me confused when I first had a look.

Answer (score 11):

### Loki didn't use the Tesseract to control people. He used his scepter, which contained the Mind Stone

I can't speak to *Captain Marvel*, since I haven't seen that movie.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that... The first time I saw _The Avengers_, I remember seeing a blue gem in the scepter, so I thought it was the Space Stone. So did the Mind Stone changed its color during the movies? Anyway, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The Mind Stone was encased in a blue outer layer... thing. Why? Who knows. Part of me wants to think the Scepter wasn't even intended to house the Mind Stone originally.

Answer (score 5):

Your recall is incorrect.

The **Mind Stone** is in the scepter that he touches people with.  The Scepter and its Mind Stone were used to give Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch their powers.  And then, the Mind Stone was broken out of the scepter to create Vision.

The **Space Stone** is in the blue cube called the Tesseract. It is used by HYDRA for weapons in WWII, borrowed by Stark in 1970, used for experiments by the humans for ship drives in the 80s and 90s, which Mar-Vell was involved in - she masqueraded as a human but was actually Kree.  I don't know how the Tesseract imbued such powers onto Carol Danvers, but it did. She had a side project to use the Tesseract to run a faster-than-light drive to help Skrull refugees relocate to far beyond the reach of the Kree.  In the 2010s it was used to attempt to create an energy source and open portals, and used to bring the Chitauri to New York City, before being returned to Asgard by Thor and Loki.

Answer (score 3):

The Tesseract has the Space Stone inside it. It can be used as the Space Stone to open portals across the universe by those who know what it really is, but the Tesseract can also be (mis)used by scientists who don't know the powers of the Space Stone as just a generic source of powerful energy. We first saw this in *Captain America: The First Avenger* when the Tesseract was used in the 1940s to charge special batteries, and then the batteries were used to power exotic tanks and guns. Those guns didn't get the Space Stone's powers, they just threw energy at a target until the target exploded.

The Kree scientist Mar-Vell must have used a similar but more advanced method to charge her spaceship's batteries using the Tesseract. The charge from the spaceship was later transferred to Captain Marvel, giving her the ability to project raw energy out of her body. Captain Marvel never tried to use the Space Stone directly, so she hasn't got its powers.

Comment: I would argue that Captain Marvel does have a Space Stone power. She can travel very fast, faster than light in fact, through outer space, presumably through some spatial manipulation thing.

Answer (score 2):

### Loki used the Scepter for mind-control

Firstly, Loki *did not* use the Space Stone to mind control in *The Avengers*, it was the Scepter (**within it, was the Mind stone that later ended up on Vision's forehead**)

---

### The Space Stone didn't give Carol her powers, the energy extracted from it did

Answering the second part about **Captain Marvel**, remember, the **Tesseract** (**Space Stone**) wasn't present during the Lighspeed engine explosion that gave Carol her powers. Mar'Vell created an energy source using the Tesseract (just like **Arnim Zola** and **Johann Schmidt** did in *Captain America: The first Avenger*).

**The energy from the explosion of the Lightspeed Engine gives Carol her powers.**

---

### More on the Infinity Stones

We cannot predict the powers a person gets from the derived power of the Infinity Stones.  Each Infinity Stone has it's own set of powers; however the powers **derived/extracted/manipulated out** from these stones have not been explained in the MCU: Case and point Captain Marvel's powers, and the twins' powers.

Remember, the **Mind Stone (Scepter)** was used to give different powers to the Maximoff twins. **Wanda (Scarlet Witch)** got her powers that include **Telekinesis, hypnosis energy projection** etc. whilst the same stone gave **Pietro** (Quicksilver) **super-speed** (*Avengers: Age of Ultron*).